# No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i am attempting to launch an intent to open a link to the android market.

android manifest portion looks like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.surreall.sixdice.Start" android:label="Six Dice" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                               
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

launching the intent looks like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String PublisherID = "pub:surreallgames";
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://search?q="+PublisherID);
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);                    
    startActivity(marketIntent);
}
```

logcat output:

```
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://search?q=pub:surreallgames }
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.surreall.sixdice.Start$9.onClick(Start.java:265)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-17 17:38:47.393: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You are running this code on an Android environment that lacks the Google Play Store, such as an emulator, Kindle Fire, etc.

If you are encountering this on an emulator, test this code path on a device that has the Play Store.

If you are encountering this on some piece of hardware that lacks the Play Store, or if you are planning on distributing your app to devices that lack the Play Store, either handle the exception or use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` to determine if your `Intent` will succeed before calling `startActivity()`.

```
if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
else
    ...
```

Comment: shooootttt, i am trying to open market:// url since 2 days on emulator because it does not have marketplace :( Phonegap 3.4

Answer (score 22):

You can use Intent.createChooser() method to safely launch the Intent. If no application exists that can handle your intent, a dialog will be displayed telling the user just that. If however Google Play Store is installed, the user can that choose to "open" the intent in Play Store.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(marketIntent, "dialogTitle"));
```

Comment: This works exactly like you said it would but one caveat is the chooser seems to have a transparent body so it's very hard to hard the message when you don't have an app installed.

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks for taking the time to share it with us!

Answer (score 18):

Better solution would be to try to open uri in Google Play app, but if there is no such app (no Activity to handle this intent) - you can just try to open uri in browser like in this example:

```
public static void rateApp(Context context) {
    try {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName())));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        viewInBrowser(context, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
    }
}

public static void viewInBrowser(Context context, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    if (null != intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `viewInBrowser` in line 5?

Comment: Yep, fixed typo.

Comment: This is the best answer...  It both handles the exception and provides an alternative means of reaching the play store

Answer (score 7):

Try adding

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

to the calling Activity.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void OpenStoreIntent(){
        String url="";
        Intent storeintent=null;
        try {
            url = "market://details?id=com.myapp.packagename";
            storeintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            storeintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            context.startActivity(storeintent);
        } catch ( final Exception e ) {
            url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp.packagename";
            storeintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            storeintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            context.startActivity(storeintent);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because I wrote:

```
Linking.openURL('www.somewebsite.com');
```

Changing the URL to `http://somewebsite.com` (or `https://somewebsite.com`, depending on the website You are targeting) fixed the problem :)