# InAppBrowser: Error loading url market://details?id=com.mydomain.myapp

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using PhoneGap 3.4 and InAppBrowser plugin.

When I try to open external urls it is launcing browser with no problem.

However when I try to launch `market://` url to rate my app I am getting following error:

```
05-13 04:30:34.527: D/InAppBrowser(2894): InAppBrowser: Error loading url market://details?id=com.mydomain.myapp:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.mydomain.myapp }
```

I can see that there is a function on InAppBrowser.java like;

```
 public String openExternal(String url) {
    try {
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // Omitting the MIME type for file: URLs causes "No Activity found to handle Intent".
        // Adding the MIME type to http: URLs causes them to not be handled by the downloader.
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
            String mimeType = webView.getResourceApi().getMimeType(uri);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,mimeType);
        } else {
            intent.setData(uri);
        }
        this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        return "";
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "InAppBrowser: Error loading url "+url+":"+ e.toString());
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```

This code looks OK to me, but it always falls into catch statement. Is there any workaround for this?

UPDATE: Code works fine on real device, does not work for emulator,
here is reason why;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11073856/929902

Comment: Can you please add the Cordova/Ionic code that you had used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who didn't read the question properly (like me) and thus didn't click the link at the end :

The problem form me was that I was running trying to open a `market://` link from an emulator that hasn't the playstore.

PS: Tested on Cordova 5.1.1 and inAppBrowser 0.6.0

Comment: Can you please add the Ionic/Cordova side code that you were using to open the market url ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add inappbrowser plugin using following CLI 
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
and use follwing code to open inappbrowser

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.removeEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Global InAppBrowser reference
    var iabRef = null;

    function iabLoadStart(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadStop(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabClose(event) {
         alert(event.type);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
    }

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         iabRef = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is ok for http:// urls but does not work for market://. Did you confirm it is working for phonegap 3.4 ?