# how to make custom image view in camera application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-camera

am working on android custom camera application the application is working but i have one issue when i capture image it saved and when i click on saved image it open mobile default view but i want own custom image view in which i can swipe left right delete and share how is it possible

```
enter code here
     public void clickedGallery(View view) {
    if (MyDebug.LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "clickedGallery");
    //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Uri uri = null;
    Media media = getLatestMedia();
    if (media != null) {
        uri = media.uri;
    }

    if (uri != null) {
        // check uri exists
        if (MyDebug.LOG)
            Log.d(TAG, "found most recent uri: " + uri);
        try {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = cr.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (pfd == null) {
                if (MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "uri no longer exists (1): " + uri);
                uri = null;
            }
            pfd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (MyDebug.LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "uri no longer exists (2): " + uri);
            uri = null;
        }
    }
    if (uri == null) {
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    if (!is_test) {
        // don't do if testing, as unclear how to exit activity to finish test (for testGallery())
        if (MyDebug.LOG)
            Log.d(TAG, "launch uri:" + uri);
        final String REVIEW_ACTION = "com.android.camera.action.REVIEW";
        try {
            // REVIEW_ACTION means we can view video files without autoplaying
            Intent intent = new Intent(REVIEW_ACTION, uri);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            if (MyDebug.LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "REVIEW_ACTION intent didn't work, try ACTION_VIEW");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073832/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent - needed to fix crash if no gallery app installed
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("blah")); // test
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                this.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                preview.showToast(null, R.string.no_gallery_app);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can customize your image view add all functionality in the class like this i create a image view as a circle imageview.


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float radius = 90.0f; // angle of round corners
        Path clipPath = new Path();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
}
```

Comment: where i use these class

Comment: you still need to customize this class according to your need

Comment: this is not according to your requirement this the the basic class which shows how to create a custom image view and use the class name with package to create a image view\

Comment: so you just use ImageView view = new ImageView(this) and set image in the view and add to the camera surface view

Comment: i created a class with xml and how to use i clicked image in this activity

Comment: You can find the Custom image view as a normal image view with findViewById method and add click listener on that imageView object