# how to show image in image view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery

I am working on android custom camera application when i click on gallery view it show mobile default gallery and show photos that i clicked but i want when i click on gallery then clicked image show in my custom view how can i implement

```
  public void clickedGallery(View view) {
    if (MyDebug.LOG)
        Log.d(TAG, "clickedGallery");
    //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    Uri uri = null;
    Media media = getLatestMedia();
    if (media != null) {
        uri = media.uri;
    }

    if (uri != null) {
        // check uri exists
        if (MyDebug.LOG)
            Log.d(TAG, "found most recent uri: " + uri);
        try {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = cr.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            if (pfd == null) {
                if (MyDebug.LOG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "uri no longer exists (1): " + uri);
                uri = null;
            }
            pfd.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (MyDebug.LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "uri no longer exists (2): " + uri);
            uri = null;
        }
    }
    if (uri == null) {
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    if (!is_test) {
        // don't do if testing, as unclear how to exit activity to finish test (for testGallery())
        if (MyDebug.LOG)
            Log.d(TAG, "launch uri:" + uri);
        final String REVIEW_ACTION = "com.android.camera.action.REVIEW";
        try {
            // REVIEW_ACTION means we can view video files without autoplaying
            Intent intent = new Intent(REVIEW_ACTION, uri);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            if (MyDebug.LOG)
                Log.d(TAG, "REVIEW_ACTION intent didn't work, try ACTION_VIEW");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073832/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent - needed to fix crash if no gallery app installed
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("blah")); // test
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                this.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                preview.showToast(null, R.string.no_gallery_app);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code you can modify the `requestCode` to whatever you would have declared in your code and you can either pass the Uri or the actual location of the file in the next activity.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && (data != null)) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null,
                        null);
                assert cursor != null;
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                if(selectedImagePath == null) {
                    selectedImagePath = getActualPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);
                }
                cursor.close();
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getActualPathFromUri(Uri selectedImageUri) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }

        File imageFileFolder = new File(getCacheDir(),"appName");
        if( !imageFileFolder.exists() ){
            imageFileFolder.mkdir();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;

        File imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, "appName-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return imageFileName.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        assert parcelFileDescriptor != null;
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: aren't you using intents to open gallery or camera?

Comment: please look my code that is only when in clicked galery then it show defalut photo viewer of mobile

Answer (score 0):

When you back from camera after you take picture or back from gallery your `onActivityResult` method will call. So override your onActivityResult like the following

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   //Read your image here and set in your imageView 
}
    }
```

Edit:

Set image to image view

Inside of the onActivityResult

```
if(data.getData()==null){
    bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
}else{
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), data.getData());
}

yourImageView.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Comment: how can i set images in this code i want to show a image in custom view i make a class image view how can i set image in this activity

Comment: thanks but i want to open image when  i clicked gallery button and open new activity and there i show image

Comment: @HarpalSingh When you get the bitmap in the `onActivityResult`, save it in a file in your cache directory and pass the filename via intent to the new Activity where you want to set image into the imageview.

Comment: No problem just save the image path and show it from next activity

Comment: Exactly that is what I mean @AmitTiwari

Comment: how can i save the file in cache directory

Comment: @HarpalSingh see my answer.