# Error handling for intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I have this helper class , it handle opening  all extensions file . But when i run app in some devices that haven't related apps to intent it's crash for example when i want to open zip file if device doesn't have related app (like winrar) ' it's crash and say :

> No activity found to handle intent .

```
public class FileOpen {

    public static void openFile(Context context, File url) throws IOException {
        // Create URI
        File file=url;
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // Check what kind of file you are trying to open, by comparing the url with extensions.
        // When the if condition is matched, plugin sets the correct intent (mime) type,
        // so Android knew what application to use to open the file
        if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
            // Word document
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
            // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Excel file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
            // RTF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
            // GIF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
            // JPG file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
            // Text file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
            // Video files
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
        } else {
            //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file

            //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
            //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
            //so you can choose which application to use
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I want to handle this error . what you think a bout that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Activity found to handle Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073832/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent)

Comment: so u want to know how to write `try{} catch(Exception e) {}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to catch this exception and alarm the user

```
try {

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, 
                    "No Application Available to view this file type", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```